# Replace text (e.g. with sed) between strings

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace

I need to replace the base URL in a .js file.

How can I replace the URL between the `"` in `baseUrl`?

```
...T0GZM",n.baseUrl="http://localhost/test"[e,n])},t.getPointe...
```

The result should be

```
...T0GZM",n.baseUrl="http://my.domain.de"[e,n])},t.getPointe...
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you share a little bit more? Based on what's shared above, you'd simply assign n.baseUrl to whatever you want in your code.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output ([mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)) and explain where is the input coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -E 's|(baseUrl="http://)[^"]+|\1my.domain.de|' file.js
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me. My result:
sed -E -i -- 's|(baseUrl=")[^"]+|\1my.domain.de|' main.*.js